# Merkle tree vs chronological merkle tree

Tags: hash-tree

I've been reading some papers about using blockchain in VANETs (Vehicular Adhoc Networks). 

Some of them have mentioned something called a chronological merkle tree (CMT). Is this different from the normal merkle tree? Here is a quote from one of them:

> The chronological Merkle tree (CMT) is the underlying data structure
>   of the conventional blockchain

this paper can be found here:
[Here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel7/6287639/8274985/08428638.pdf)

Comment: I presume that this is just a Merkle tree where the branches / leafs are chronologically ordered according to a point in time that is apparent from the data that was hashed. There must be a way to know which data is first when hashing anything, after all; an unordered set would be able to produce different hashes as you need to do some kind of ordering before you can start to hash.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes so for example we could say that the leftmost leaf is always the oldest (has an older timestamp) among other leafs?

Comment: Yeah, that was I meant, and hopefully also what was meant by VANET, but I don't know that protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assign indices to the leaves of the Merkle tree: from left to right we number the leaves $0$, $1$, $\ldots$, $2^n-1$, or 0000, 0001, ..., 1111 in binary.
When we now walk from the root to a leaf, at each node 0 means taking the left branch and 1 means taking the right branch (when viewed from above).

Initially we have an empty tree. If we start adding elements, we need to insert them at some index (= at some leaf).

If we choose the the indices incrementally, we obtain a **dense** or **chronological** Merkle tree. There are only leaves on the left, all the leaves on the right are empty. This also means that there is a large empty subtree on the right.

If we choose the indices randomly, we obtain a **sparse** Merkle tree. Empty and non-empty leaves are randomly distributed across the tree.